# Why more than one JQuery functions are not Calling from Codebehind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, function, code-behind

I am trying to call two simple `functions` from my asp.net `codebehind` and only one function is working and not the other.

Here are my functions:

```
  function Clear() {
                     alert('Cleared');
                 }

  function Add() {
                     alert('Added');
                 }
```

I have a simple button click event as shown below:

```
 Public Sub btnProcess_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnProcess.Click

    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "Script", "Clear();", True)
    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "Script", "Add();", True)

 End Sub
```

If I comment out one function the other is working and the vice-versa but not both at a time.

Comment: 1. have you tried to look at generated html? 2. any js errors?

Comment: @Zerkms-Yes, I have checked them using firebug but havent got any erros.

Comment: i think because its all about the alert try some other action and it will work perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs for RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx) state that the script key have to be distinct, otherwise they are seen as duplicates (which is what is happening in your case).

Answer (score 2):

You need a different key for the second script.

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "Script", "Add();", True)
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "Script2", "Add();", True)
```